# Need to display previous folder in the modified zshrc file, how do I do it?

Tags: zshrc

This is my current configuration of the zshrc file for showing git branch which results in showing the current folder with the git branch (if present)

```
function parse_git_branch() {
    git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -n -e 's/^\* \(.*\)/[\1]/p'
}

setopt PROMPT_SUBST
export PROMPT='%F{cyan}%.%f %F{blue}$(parse_git_branch)%f%F{normal}$%f '
```

Instead of . in the PROMPT, I tried ~ but then it will show the complete path of the directory, but I wish to only see the current directory and the previous one. How should I proceed?

```
export PROMPT='%F{cyan}%.%f %F{blue}$(parse_git_branch)%f%F{normal}$%f '
```

If I am currently in Documents/gitRepos/project1, terminal would show me `project1 [master]`, what I want is `gitRepos/project1 [master]`

Comment: What do you mean by "the previous [directory]"? Where you were `cd`-ed before you ran `cd ~/src/project`?

Comment: I mean if I am currently in Documents/gitRepos/project1, terminal would show me project1 [master], what I want is gitRepos/project1 [master]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zsh [has this built in](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html):

> ```
> %c
> %.
> %C
> ```
>
> Trailing component of the current working directory.
> An integer may folow the `'%'` to get more than one component. Unless
> `'%C'` is used, tilde contraction is performed first. These are
> deprecated as `%c` and `%C` are equivalent to `%1~` and `%1/.`,
> respectively, while explicit positive integers have the same effect as
> for the latter two sequences.

So, simply replace `%.` with `%2.` or `%2~` or whatever you prefer here.